# Search a regex containing special characters

Tags: python

I want to find if there is a pattern `$*.*` in text.
But i cannot figure out how to do that with regular expressions in python.

Comment: just escape the dollar sign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the dollar *and* the dot:

```
re.search(r'\$\.', inputstring)
```

Rules of thumb:

1. Use a raw string literal, so you don't have to double slashes (both Python and regular expressions derive meaning from the backslash)
2. When in doubt, escape the character to make it match a literal character.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a specific substring, you don't even need a regular expression for this. This should do:

```
"$." in my_string
```

Example:

```
>>> "$." in "tes$.t"
True
>>> "$." in "test"
False
```